# Linux Overlapped I/O TCP socket server not responsing to C# ASync Client correctly

Tags: c#, linux, sockets, asynchronous, overlapped-io

I am trying to code a simple functioning echo socket client/server. I have managed to get a Synchronous server with a client to work, but now I need an asynchronous.

If I use Microsofts versions it is functioning good, ASync **Server**:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

Microsoft ASync **Client**:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

What I am trying now is to get **Microsoft Async Client** communicate with a **Linux C++ Overlapped I/O Server**:

http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Linux-C-Overlapped-Server-and-Client-Socket-Example/77220

Here the problems begin. The connection is established and I can send a message to the Server, the server responds echoing back the message (according to debug and terminal output) but the Microsoft ASync Client never gets the response on its socket.

Is it impossible to connect an ASync Client to an Overlapped I/O server? I am not sure why the reply from the server never reaches the client. Debugging the Microsoft ASync Client tells me that the `Receive` function never get passed this line of code:

```
receiveDone.WaitOne();
```

receiveDone is a ManualResetEvent:

```
private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
            new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Context:

```
// Receive the response from the remote device.
Receive(client);
receiveDone.WaitOne();
```

Here is the callback function for receiving, setting the receiveDone when done. `bytesRead` never exceeds 0.:

```
private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        msg("Fail ReceiveCallback: " + e.Message, false);
    }
}
```

Anyway, this code is working when connected to an ASync Server, but not the Overlapped I/O server, so actually I am asking for what to change in the [Overlapped I/O server code](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Linux-C-Overlapped-Server-and-Client-Socket-Example/77220), for it to send back messages that the ASync Client can receive?

This is the output from the server if sent `Hello World` from the ASync Client:

```
root@deb7sve:/home/petlar/Host/SockServer# g++ OverlappedServer.cpp -o os.out -lpthread
root@deb7sve:/home/petlar/Host/SockServer# ./os.out
---------------------
Received connection from 10.0.2.2
Read 13 bytes from 4
Sent 13 bytes to 4
```

Comment: This code is not asynchronous since presumable a thread is waiting on the event. This is pointless MSDN sample code. You get horrible async code and don't get any of the benefits.

Comment: Is the server closing the connection when it is done sending?

Comment: I am not sure if Microsoft example is good asynchronous example, but I will try improve the client later as soon as simple communication with the server can be established. No the server waits for more packets, and echoes them back to client. Up to 100 clients if I read the code correct, but the sample code lacks cleanup and reuse of sockets and so on, so it is very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That client code only sets the event when the connection is shut down. According to your comment the server does not close the connection. That's why the event is never set.

Throw the client code away and rewrite it using simple synchronous code. 50% of your code is devoted to making async IO (in a broken way). Async IO is not about improving network efficiency. It's there to save thread resources. Chances are it's not needed on the client.

Comment: Never thought the Client was waiting for a close of the connection. I will consider this, thanks!

Comment: Great, it worked! As soon as I tested closing the socket serverside after an echo response the echo message showed up on the client. Okay, I understand now that the client code needs to be brushed up, thanks!